# Receive input stream via rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to send a file via rest. As some posts indicate, it should be sent as input stream because file's size may be considerable (hundreds of MB as for example). Client side example looks like this:

```
public void post() throws IOException {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/app-server/file");

        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("d:/111.txt");
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addBinaryBody("inStream", inStream, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "fileName");
        builder.addTextBody("text", "...file description here...", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
             CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {
        }
    }
```

Rest controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/app-server/file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveFile(@RequestBody HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        /* some code here */
        return new ResponseEntity<>("fileKey", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=1509983827081;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
```

I can't find if the mistake is on the client side, server side or both of them.

Comment: So this is in fact a Spring-MVC question. Which version are you using? Running on which server (and version)?

Comment: MVC? No, there is no view at all. There is a rest controller that has to receive a request containing input stream, sent via rest. Spring Boot 1.5.8, embedded Tomcat

Comment: That's irrelevant. The web framework of Spring, that you're using, is named Spring-MVC. What happens when you remove `post.setHeader("Content-type"...` and the `consumes` attribute of your mapping?

Comment: The same exception: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=Rtcbgw9NtRR0N_vs9DWIFFRokt890DpvMzGmly;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: I have eventually found the cause of the problem. I should have used this signature: saveFile(HttpServletRequest request). Now it works